# Nodejs/Mongoose pull objectId from Array doesn't work in ternary expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

Am trying to do simple thing, pulling a userId from an array with mongoose on mongo database and updating the object by findByIdAndUpdate method. here i am using the '$pull' '$addToSet' methods like a toggle to add and remove userId from array. in short my goal is to like when cliked and unlike on the second click. so i put the '$pull' and '$addToSet' in ternary expression and used it in the method findByIdAndUpdate() like so:

```
exports.getLikeCounts = async (req, res) => {

  const likes = Review({_id: req.params.id}).likes.map(obj => obj.toString());

  //ternarry expression

  const likeOperator = likes.includes(req.user._id) ? '$pull' : '$addToSet';

  const likeReview = await Review
    .findByIdAndUpdate( {_id: req.params.id},
      {[likeOperator]: {likes: req.user._id}},
      {new: true}
    )
  res.json(likeReview);
}
```

In here it only adds but doesn't pull the userId from array on the second click.
i could't understand what am missing any help would be appreciated and thanks.

the structure of my model looks like this:

```
likes:[
    { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
  ]
```

NB: if i use the pull and addtoset directly like so: {'$pull' or '$addToSet': {likes: req.user._id}} for test it works but in ternary expression like how i used above doesn't work both but only the addtoset.

Comment: The issue is not with the  ternary expression. You converted the `_id` in likes to `String` at `obj.toString()`, are you sure `req.user._id` is also `String` when you compare it with `likes.includes`? I guess they should all be `ObjectId` and you don't need any conversion. Also `.findByIdAndUpdate()` accepts `_id` as the first parameter so it should be `req.params.id` not `{ _id: req.params.id }`

Comment: The include method searches for data in an array. arr.include, but you're passing object.

Comment: thanks @Asif and TheeSritabtim for your answers. **Asif**  the data in an array is all in strings as am changing the obj to string. but even though i change the userId to string attaching to it user._id.toString() or passing the object direct with out changing to string the array obj and the userId. in the .findByIdAndUpdate() method i used the req.params.id but still nothing changes. still stack on this.

Comment: My guess is that `req.user._id` is `ObjectId`. In that case just remove `.map(obj => obj.toString())`, that should work

Comment: Thanks for ur ideas @TheeSritabtim it gives me more options it does the same effect but still nothing changed. with ur idea the result looks like this:                          
exports.getLikeCounts = async (req, res) => {

  const likes = Review({_id: req.params.id}).likes;
  
  const likeOperator = likes.includes(req.user._id) ? '$pull' : '$addToSet';

  const likeReview = await Review
    .findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
      {[likeOperator]: {likes: req.user._id}},
      {new: true}
    )
    console.log('the liked review:', likeReview);
  res.json(likeReview);
}

Comment: With my suggestion. You will always get `$addToSet` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you retrieve the likes, you have to get it from the database with `Review.findById()` not just `Review()`

```
const { likes } = await Review.findById(req.params.id);

const likeOperator = likes.includes(req.user._id) ? '$pull' : '$addToSet'; // this is fine already

const likeReview = await Review
  .findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, // this accepts _id
    { [likeOperator]: { likes: req.user._id } },
    { new: true }
  )
  res.json(likeReview);
```

Comment: Briliant @TheeSritabtim you are awsome thank you so much !! that was exactly what i was supposed to do. i wasn't retrieving the likes in a correct way. thanks again u r the best ....